# Does the liver produce less cholesterol if a person eats a lot of cholesterol?

Tags: liver, cholesterol

I can't find any real study on this. I only found couple of blogs like [this](https://www.everydayhealth.com/columns/paging-dr-gupta/what-do-i-need-to-know-about-my-diet-and-cholesterol/):
​

*“It turns out the liver does a really good job of regulating the balance between the cholesterol the body makes and the cholesterol we eat,” says Brown. “If we eat more cholesterol, the liver will produce less cholesterol, and vice versa.”*

I'm not sure if this is true or not.

Comment: The statement is true, but, as such, does not allow any conclusions about eventual benefits or harms of consuming cholesterol.

Answer (score 3):

"The net daily synthesis of cholesterol is equal to the amount of cholesterol lost in the feces minus the dietary cholesterol"

The body synthesizes an amount approximately equal to the amount it absorbs

Source:
Balancing Cholesterol Synthesis and Absorption in the Gastrointestinal Tract
David E. Cohen, M.D., Ph.D.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2390860/